# Why Xelement.Parse() throws an exception?

Tags: c#, xaml, exception

```
XElement.Parse("<Style TargetType=\"TextBlock\" x:Key=\"LabelStyle\"><Setter Property=\"TextWrapping\" Value=\"Wrap\"/></Style>");
```

This throws an exception, why?

I want to join an XML document with some styles so it dynamically renders correctly in the app, because the document misses some styles(i.e this one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine the problem is that you're using a namespace alias of `x`, but there's no indication of what that namespace alias *means* - what URI it corresponds to.

If you include

```
xmlns:x="http://...."
```

(with the appropriate namespace URI) then I suspect it'll be fine.

Comment: I would not be surprise if this is accepted as the answer. :)

Comment: How could I not, this is Jon SKeet after all... But first, could you tell how can I include this, because this is not the header of the file(it's not UserControl, nor Window) and I'm not very familiar with xaml?

Comment: @John: What do you mean "how can I include this"? You just add it as another attribute within the element text. You should be able to find out what `x` refers to by looking at the real XAML - look at the root element, which is probably where it will be defined.